# FSL Trigger Exceeding Apex CPU Time Limit

Tags: apex, integration, governorlimits, fsl

I am attempting to integrate Salesforce using some middleware.

What the integration does it take an Excel sheet, and from that sheet create a Work Order, Service Appointment and Assigned Resource record for each row.

When I run this integration, the Work Order and Service Appointments are created as expected - however, the AssignedResource creation fails, with the following error message:

*CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY:FSL.TR021_AssignedResource_AfterInsert: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded:--*

Judging from this error message, it seems that there is a trigger on the AssignedResource object which is exceeding the CPU time limit. The trigger is part of the FSL managed package, so it can't be disabled or changed.

Does anyone know what this trigger does, and if there is a way to disable it or work around the issue to avoid the error?

There is no other automation/triggers on the AssignedResource object. I have also tried lowering the batch size to 25, but the error still occurs.

Comment: My suggestion is to ensure you send the data from excel to Salesforce in smaller chunks, not all in one go. Each separate request gets its own CPU limits, so if you send too many objects together you can hit limits like this.

Comment: My bet would be to go with the chunk size of 1 if even this fails then you will probably have to contact the package creators to further troubleshoot.